# gauge load or performance of database using a query for monitoring

Tags: sql, sql-server, monitoring

I would like to get a metric that would give some rough idea of the MS SQL server load.

I'm using this query currently executed through a remote service every 5 minutes, so I don't want to add unnecessary load.

```
SELECT AVG(last_elapsed_time) as avg_last_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
```

is there another option that would give a more meaningful snapshot of the database that is worth monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have tools for it. I think You will find [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187830%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179428.aspx) sites usefull.

You can say what You want about SQL server, but these tools are quite ok. :)